# Disable OpenLDAP replication

Tags: ubuntu, ldap, replication, openldap

I set up openldap replication so that if my primary LDAP server were to die, I would have another LDAP server ready to use just in case. I used the directions on [Ubuntu's site](https://help.ubuntu.com/12.10/serverguide/openldap-server.html#openldap-server-replication) to set up the replication.

If my primary LDAP server does die and the secondary server needs to take over, I'll need to disable that replication, right? How do I disable the replication and let the secondary server just be its own server after the primary server has died?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is a P2P replication topology in which both of your LDAP servers are masters (i.e., both can receive updates from your applications and are configured to replicate updates to each other), then, no. You should not stop replication as you need your secondary server to accumulate updates in its replication queue and start applying them to the primary as soon as it becomes online. If your secondary server is not a master but replica, then you don't need to worry about stopping replication as your primary server (i.e., the master) is dead, therefore not replicating.

Comment: My secondary server is a replica only. So when the master dies, as long as that doesn't break the secondary, that's all I need. Thanks for your answer!